# Fluid Field Not working

Tags: fields, fluid-field

I'm working in EE 5.1.1 and trying to use a fluid field for the first time.

I've created the field and added the nested fields however on the publish page it won't let me select a field.

[image]

When clicking on the sub fields nothing happens.

Please advise.

Comment: What kinds of fields are the three you've added to the fluid field?

Comment: We have a similar issue, do you have javascript error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'label' of undefined"